# Bounded ball measure on compact metric space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

Fix $c>1$.  Let $(X,d)$ be a separable compact metric space, does there necessarily exist a Borel probability measure $\nu$ on $(X,d)$ such that

- $\operatorname{sup}_{x \in X,r>0}\frac{\nu(\mathrm{Ball}(x,cr))}{\nu(\mathrm{Ball}(x,r))}<\infty$,
- $\nu(\mathrm{Ball}(x,r))>0$ for every $x \in X$ and $r>0$.

Comment: What is $c$? Also, why doesn't the second point imply the first? Or do you want some uniform boundedness?

Comment: I clarified c and point 1. It isn't implied by the second one anymore (excuse my typo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you asking if there is a $c>1$ and a measure $\nu$ with this property? And is the first condition supposed to hold with a uniform upper bound? (If not, any probability measure satisfying the second condition would work, as Steve points out.)

If so, you are asking for the existence of a non-trivial "doubling measure". A necessary and sufficient condition for a complete metric space to carry a non-trivial doubling measure is that it is a "doubling metric space".

A metric space is a "doubling metric space" if every ball $B(x,r)$ can be covered by $N$ balls of radius $r/2$, where $N$ is a fixed constant. See wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space

If a complete metric space carries a non-trivial doubling measure, it must be a doubling metric space, by a fairly standard covering argument. (See, for example, Heinonen's book *Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces*.)

The reverse implication, that every complete doubling metric space carries a non-trivial doubling measure, is more difficult. It was proven by Vol'berg-Konyagin in the compact case and Luukkainen-Saksman in the general case. See Luukkainen-Saksman (https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-02/S0002-9939-98-04201-4/S0002-9939-98-04201-4.pdf) for the details and references.

Comment: Doubling property is definitely sufficient but I'm not sure it's necessary.  Here c is given and fixed but I'm not requiring that the balls all be compared by the same doubling constant.  For example, I think this should hold for the unit ball in $\ell^2$ which isn't doubling

Comment: @AIM_BLB The metric doubling condition is necessary. See Proposition 59 in Measure Theory that you can find here:  https://sites.google.com/view/piotr-hajasz/teaching/lecture-notes?authuser=0

Comment: Hi Piotr, thanks I worked it out on the Tram home and indeed it is necessary.  I just found it surprising since the paper of Ambrosio which it comes from treated the two cases separately.